# How to check battery removed using rxandroidble

Tags: android, rxandroidble

I want to get status 8 or battery removed using RxAndroidBle. I'm using this

```
to get States
bleDevice?.observeConnectionStateChanges()
?.compose(ReplayingShare.instance())
?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())?.subscribe(::onStateSuccess,::onStateFailure)
```

Getting this

> CONNECTING("CONNECTING"), CONNECTED("CONNECTED"),
>   DISCONNECTED("DISCONNECTED"), DISCONNECTING("DISCONNECTING");

Don't know how to make sure disconnection is due to battery removal

Answer (score 0):

To get the status from a `RxBleGattException` one would need to use at least [`com.polidea.rxandroidble2:rxandroidble:1.7.0`](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/releases/tag/release-1.7.0-rxjava2)

Anyway the thing you want to achieve is not be possible by using the `RxBleDevice.observeConnectionStateChanges()` as this only gives info about the state change — *not* information about the cause of the change. To get the actual error that caused a particular disconnection one should check for the `BleException` that is emitted from `RxBleDevice.establishConnection()`.

Comment: Is it available now, Please provide the version

Comment: Updated the answer